# How select one element of a list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to split filename and extension : foo.bar

```
  - name: split file
    set_fact:
      myvar: "{{ myfile | splitext | to_json }}"
```

With splitext i get a list of 2 elements.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "foo",
        ".bar"
    ]
}
```

I have to use the first but i can't :

```
  - name: test
    debug:
      msg="{{ myvar[0] }}"
```

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "["
}
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `to_json` filter with `list` filter:

```
- name: split file
  set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ myfile | splitext | list }}"
```

---

`to_json` produces a JSON string (`["foo", ".bar"]`) and because strings are represented internally as lists of characters, `myvar[0]` refers to its first character (`[`).

`debug` output is confusing in this example, as `msg` will be templated and displayed just like it was a list.

You can always check the type with `myvar | type_debug`, for strings you will see `unicode` (or `AnsibleUnicode`).